# Unix - regarding & and ps

Tags: c, unix, ps

I'm working on a hw assignment and was wondering if someone with a bit more Unix experience could explain what is meant by the following question:

```
Run sample program 1 in the background with &
Using the ps utility with appropriate options, observe and report the PIDs and the status  of your processes.
```

Sample program 1 is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
    puts("Before fork");
    fork();
    sleep(10);
    puts("After fork");
}
```

I compiled and ran:

```
./fork_demo &
```

What is the best way to use ps with this running in background? I'm only looking for guidance here and this is a tiny portion of a HW assignment. I've already done the major stuff!

Comment: Just type `ps`. What's the problem? The forked program will sleep for 10 seconds, so there is plenty of time for typing `ps` command.

Comment: I figure there is a better way of reporting them than simply ps?

Comment: You might want to use ps to look at the process tree, as I believe the assignment is trying to show you the relationship between the PIDs of the parent and child.  Just type `man ps` in a terminal to get more info.

Comment: You can print the PID of the process right after `fork` and before `sleep` with `getpid`: http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpid

Comment: I also didn't know if "status" of processes had a significant meaning other than just the existence of the processes. I suppose I am over thinking the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ps -ef | grep fork_demo
```

or

```
ps aux | grep fork_demo
```

Not knowing which are the "right parameters" for your assignment, I took some guesses.

Answer (score 4):

```
./fork_demo &
ps
```

Explanation:

`&` forces the process before it (`fork_demo`) into the background. At that point, you can run another command (like `ps`).